# Passing Line Break "\n" or "<br>" from the Main Function to Jinja

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have a list with the name of colors:

```
colors = [red, green, blue]
```

And I want it to be printed out on my web page as

0. red
1. green
2. blue

I tried this by using an argument in my HTML template `{{colors_out}}`, where I pass a string with `"\n"` to it as follows:

```
colors_out = ""
for i in range(len(colors)):
   colors_out += (str(i) + ". " + colors[i] + "\n")
```

However, that does nothing but add a space between my colors. It prints out these:

```
0. red 1. green 2. blue
```

instead of my desired format. I tried replacing `"n"` with `"<br>"` in the for loop above too, but then it will result in:

```
0. red<br>1. green<br>2. blue<br>
```

Comment: Html doesn't respect newlines by default. Add a `style="white-space: pre;"` to your element to make it. (or just switch it to a `<pre>` tag)

Comment: Why not use a `<ol>` instead?

Comment: I tried ```<ol>```, but it doesn't work either :(

Comment: I tried ```style="white-space: pre;"```, and it works wonderfully! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, which you can try to use a for loop in Jinja2 in your HTML.

You can simply pass a list to the HTML and then use for loop in Jinja2 along with the

tags to print the outputs on seperate lines -

For example in your case -

In your Flask code -

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/colors', methods=["GET","POST"])
def test():

    #your other code

    colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
    return render_template('index.html',color=colors)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And your HTML code -

just add this for loop, where i iterates over all the colors and print them in seperate lines

```
{% for i in color %}
<p>{{ i }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

you can also use any other tag as per your requirement, it will still print on new line.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! This works great and is also reproducible for other cases! Thank you so much!